# How can I solve the 'ReactCropperElement' not found error when using react-cropper?

Tags: reactjs

Compiled with problems:
ERROR in ./src/components/cropping/cropping.js 15:30-49
export 'ReactCropperElement' (imported as 'ReactCropperElement') was not found in 'react-cropper' (possible exports: Cropper, default)

Try: functional component
const [cropData, setCropData] = useState("#");
const cropperRef = useRef(null);

Expecting:
Wanted to create the cropper